# Android Studio Gson to Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, gson, internal-storage

Hello im a beginner in Android Studio, I have a problem with saving an Object to a file.

First I use the Gson libary to make the Object 'Appdata' to an JSON String and I save this String
in the file Appdata.txt

Here is my InternalStorage.java class

```
package com.example.fragment.AppData.Logic;

import android.content.Context;

import com.example.fragment.UserInterface.MainActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class InternalStorage {

    private static InternalStorage instance = null;
    private static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public boolean saveData(AppData saveData) {

        gson.toJson(saveData);
        String s = gson.toJson(saveData);

        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = MainActivity.getInstance().getContext().openFileOutput("appdata.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fOut.write(s.getBytes());
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public AppData loadData() {

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = MainActivity.getInstance().getContext().openFileInput("appdata.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null))
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        String s = sb.toString();
        AppData newData = null;
        try {
            newData = gson.fromJson(s, AppData.class);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newData;
    }


}
```

I use this method in the Appdata Class :

```
  public AppData loadData() {
        return internalStorage.loadData();
    }

    public boolean saveAppData() {
       return internalStorage.saveData(this);
    }
```

Here I use the Appdata in the MainActivity. (I don't think its neccessary to post all 3 Classes)

```
  appData.loadData();
    //change something in AppData
    if(!appData.saveAppData()){
        //Inform the User about the not working Save 
    }
```

The Problem is that changes are not saved.

Comment: `sb.append(line);` That should be `sb.append(line+"\n");`. Otherwise you throw away your lines.

Comment: `public void saveData(` No good to make that a void function. Make it boolean and let it return true or false. The caller should check the return value and inform the user if something goes wrong.

Comment: @blackapps It does not change anything still not able to save data

Comment: Please adapt your code here too before we continue.

Comment: blackapps the problem with the public void saveData is that it seems okay but it does not work so atm it would always return true.

Comment: Nice. Now please adapt your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you are beginner in Android development not just in Android studio. Do not make an Activity as a Singleton. About the question. If you wanna just save an object android provide a `SharedPreferences` https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

But if you really need to create a file I think you just forgot to get access to permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure how to do it, i thought saving data in files would be good. I'll try to do it that way. Thanks :D